# jQuery validation error for validator.format

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui

Is someone able to solve this error? is with jquery validation 1.13.1 and jquery 1.11.1 :

```
  uncaught exception: $.format has been deprecated. Please use $.validator.format instead.
```

Whenever I disable any validation form I have ,it still show the error, so it's basically something on the validation file code isn't it?  not in my form validation file where I use it like this:

```
    $("#free_validation").add("#validation-form").validate({
        ignore:'',
        rules: {
            title:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                alphanumericwithpunc: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            title: {
                required: "Escriba el titulo",
                minlength: "Al menos 2 caracteres",
                alphanumericwithpunc: "Sólo alfanumérico"
            }
        }
    });
```

And my method like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphanumericwithpunc", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[\wàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,;.:'\\\_\-\¿?¡!&%$€#()\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and basic punctuation only please");
```

as they specified in their [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) :

Any help much appreciated!

The problem was my method, so i used like this now:

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphanumericwithpunc", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[\wàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,;.:'\\\_\-\¿?¡!&%$€#()\s]+$/i.test(value);
    }, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct value"));
```

Comment: You neglected to include the code for `alphanumericwithpunc`, and I'm guessing that's where the problem is.  I see no issues if I get rid of that bit.  See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/5Lkgyzq0/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new format, like,

```
messages: {
            title: {
                required: "Escriba el titulo",
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Al menos 2 caracteres"),
                alphanumericwithpunc: jQuery.validator.format("Sólo alfanumérico")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know you get that from https://github.com/properapp/jquery-validation/issues/3 but as I said before, even if I set none form validation code , the error comes, which make consider the possibility this to be a bug?

Comment: Have to come back now,  the comment from @Ryley give me a way but marked yours as the answer since, is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably solved by now, but thought of sharing my version of the issue and how I solved it. Please note **this doesn't directly address the core issue, but only shows how to stop that error message from appearing**.

I was facing the same exact problem - just included the following two libraries into my project (which already had jQuery included)

1. jquery.validate.js
2. additional-methods.js (some addons on the original validation library)

and there we go, the error popped up on the console.

I did a bit of research and found out the the code which throws the error is present in line no 1313 of the file **jquery.validate.js** and looks like:

```
$.format = function deprecated() {
  throw "$.format has been deprecated. Please use $.validator.format instead.";
};
```

I commented out the **throw** statement and the error vanished. I tested by adding some validation rules into my forms and they kept working great as usual. So, not a clean solution, but gets rid of the ugly error message.